# I made simulation, and objects disappear

Tags: python

I made this source code, simulating how big group of pedestrian act 
I left descriptions on the source code, and I can't find out the problem here.It is a psuchological decision model
Please read the description on the source code and please check what is wrong in my source code. Objects are not supposed to disappear but they do 
Please, Help me.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import time
import numpy


class MapGrid():
    def __init__(self, map_width, map_height): # create a coordinate with dimension map_width * map_height

        self.map_width = map_width
        self.map_height = map_width

        self.outside_terrain_grid = self._generate_empty_noise_grid(self.map_width, self.map_height)

    def _generate_empty_noise_grid(self, map_width, map_height): 
        ''' 
            creates objects with value of 0,1,2 when y < 20 
            0 means nothing, 1 is a object that moves with velocity 1, 2 is a object that moves with velocity 2
            and random sequence of 1 or 2 will be added to objects(value of 1,2) which is desire
            they are going to move to right
        '''
        number_count = 0 
        sum_velocity = 0
        new_map_grid = []
        for x in range(map_width):

            new_map_grid.append([])
            for y in range(map_height):
                if y < 20: 
                    new_map_grid[x].append(random.choice([0,1,2]))
                else:
                    new_map_grid[x].append(0)

                if new_map_grid[x][y] != 0:
                    number_count += 1
                    sum_velocity += new_map_grid[x][y]
                    new_map_grid[x][y] += self._individual_desire(sum_velocity, number_count)

        return new_map_grid


    def _individual_desire(self, sum_velocity, number_count): 
        '''
        Gaussian destribution of random number(1 or 2)
        '''
        mu = 1.5
        sigma = 0.125
        average_velocity = sum_velocity / number_count
        critical_number = numpy.random.normal(mu, sigma)

        value = average_velocity - critical_number

        if value < 0:
            return 1
        else: 
            return 2


    def _generate_outside_terrain(self, empty_outside_terrain_grid, number_of_generations):
        '''
        This method creates a new list that will represent next phase
        For example, For example, in the grid[10][20] and in the 1st phase, 
        there was object with value 1 in the coordinate grid[0][0] 
        and it has velocity of 2, It moves to grid[0][2]
        and there is also change in velocity and desire in surrounding interactions 
        assume that there is object i and j and j is right in front of i
        Here, top_mid is j, and mid is i 
        if d_i(desire of i) <= v_j, then v_i = d_i
        elif d_i > v_j, then i moves to right or left with probability of 0.5 
        continue in the same direction
        '''
        grid = empty_outside_terrain_grid
        number_of_generations = number_of_generations

        for x in range(number_of_generations):
            next_grid = []
            for column_index, column in enumerate(grid): 
                next_column = []
                next_grid.append(next_column)

                for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):

                    next_column.append(0) # append doesn't seem to work so I created dimension with full of 0 and change the value 0~4

                for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):
                    #I made exception considering when index is bigger than map_width
                    try:
                        top_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index - 1]
                    except IndexError:
                        tile_index - 1 < 0
                    mid = grid[column_index][tile_index]

                    try:
                        d_top_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index + 1] % 2 
                    except IndexError:
                        tile_index + 1 > map_width

                    d_mid = grid[column_index][tile_index] % 2 

                    try:
                        v_top_mid = math.floor((grid[column_index][tile_index+1] + 1) / 2)
                    except IndexError:
                        tile_index + 1 > map_width

                    v_mid = math.floor((grid[column_index][tile_index] + 1) / 2)

                    the_value = grid[column_index][tile_index]


                    #Below is making surrounding interaction

                    if d_mid <= v_top_mid:
                        grid[column_index][tile_index] == d_mid * 2
                        try: 
                            next_grid[column_index][tile_index+v_mid] = the_value
                        except IndexError:
                            tile_index+v_mid > map_width

                    else:
                        next_grid[column_index-1].append(the_value)

        grid = next_grid
        return next_grid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # general map stats
    map_width = 140
    map_height = 30

    # start with one generation
    tile_size = 8

    map_grid = MapGrid(map_width, map_height)
    #print map_grid.outside_terrain_grid

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))
    zero_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1)) 
    zero_tile.fill((0,0,0))
    one_tile = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
    one_tile.fill((255,255,255))
    two_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    two_tile.fill((255,0,0))
    three_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    three_tile.fill((0,0,204))
    four_tile = pygame.Surface((1,1))
    four_tile.fill((0,255,0))

    colors = {0: zero_tile, 1: one_tile, 2:two_tile, 3:three_tile, 4:four_tile}

    background = pygame.Surface((map_width * tile_size,map_height * tile_size))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    first_gen = True
    timer = 12

    running = True
    while running == True:
        clock.tick(3)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        if first_gen:
            themap = map_grid.outside_terrain_grid
        else:
            themap = map_grid._generate_outside_terrain(themap, 1)

        for column_index, column in enumerate(themap):
            for tile_index, tile in enumerate(column):
                screen.blit(colors[tile], (tile_index * tile_size, column_index * tile_size))

        pygame.display.flip()

        if first_gen:
            timer -= 1
            if timer < 0:
                first_gen = False

    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The error is very explicit: `next_grid[column_index][tile_index+v_mid] = the_value` uses an index out of range. So one of `column_index` or `tile_index+v_mid` is out of the range of the array.

Comment: I changed the question! If it is okay, can you answer to my new question?? :)

Comment: The least you should do is explain exactly what is wrong. Do not refer us to the code to figure it out. That's your job: explain what is the expected behavior vs. actual output. provide a few examples and a way to reproduce the issue. In case you're getting an error - post the full stacktrace and show us which line in the code triggers it. If you want others to help you - you should make some kind of effort to help yourself first! Help us help you ;)

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm not getting any error but simulation does not produce expected behavior what they supposed to do is all object does not disppear and move right to the end of map_width I'm not sure what is happening but there are two cases
1. They do not move to right

Comment: 2. they move but overlapped?